# Attempt to write to a readonly database error

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel

I have created a new Laravel app utilising SQLite database for user login system. I am experiencing a weird issue where I receive the following error:

> ```
> > SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database
> > (SQL: update "users" set "remember_token" =
> > HH0dtQYZ5BgoOpya1hNRUrFvIZF0dcYqdIvAjz0k6CbTKBqah7wWPdQbgzzL,
> > "updated_at" = 2016-06-18 12:47:43 where "id" = 1)
> ```

I initially thought there is some permission issue with my SQLite db file however the correct user has permission to access the file and I have set chmod to `755`.
The issue ONLY occurs when logging in the first time, if I refresh the page (and resent form data) the app logins in successfully. I do not experience this issue for any other DB actions within my app.

Comment: The folder that houses the database file must be writeable.

Check your permissions. or look at this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319112/sqlite-read-only-database

Comment: The parent directory also has the same permissions `755`

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who might need this, **check your file permissions**.

If your `database.sqlite` file is under `database/`, set the permissions to 775 (755 did not work for me).

```
$ chmod -R 775 database
```

It may also be worth setting the group to `www-data` and owner to yourself.

```
$ chgrp -R www-data database
$ chown -R USERNAME database
```

obviously replace `database` with the path to the folder your `.sqlite` database is. Also check the permissions after any migrations commands, or `passport:install`. I'm sure it was user error, but at one point I thought I had set file permissions on the directory recursively, but the actual `.sqlite` file had somehow reverted to `644` and both owner and group were my user.

That may have just been due to me messing up a build script, but my point is - checking a second time is quicker than digging through SO questions.

Also worth noting, if you have some routes working, but others failing with a 500 error, check that you actually have at least 1 row of data in your tables. I would recommend creating seeders and running `php artisan passport:install` to generate some initial data.

Comment: 660 will give read/write permissions to both user and group. More than adequate

Answer (score 5):

The problem, as it turns out, is that the *PDO SQLite driver* requires that if you are going to do a write operation (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `DROP`, etc.), then the folder the database resides in must have write permissions, as well as the actual database file.

Comment: This. The parent folder of the database also needs write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The PDO sqlite requires that you set the directory to read/write permission.
To do this add chown www-data before the database path.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: ' chown www-data ./dev-module/database/database.sqlite',
  syncOnAssociation: true,
});
```