# Attempt to write a readonly database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a windows form application. It works properly when I run it from VS-2015 editor/compiler. But when I create a setup file and install it in windows then it runs very slowly. It takes many times to read data from database. My database is sqlite3. This is issue about software run time.

There is another problem, When software try to write any data in database, then it shows an error "attempt to write readonly database".

But my database file is not readonly file. Here I get some solutions but I can't solve this problem.

Is this programatic or code level problem or other dependencies problem. How can I solve this.

Comment: Does the Application/User have sufficient permission to write in the application directory? Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319112/sqlite-read-only-database).