# Laravel + SQLite = SQLSTATE[HY000]General Error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: php, linux, laravel, sqlite, ubuntu

I'm trying to delete a db.sqlite file, create it again and then insert some info into this DB all in the same method. This is the method I'm using:

```
public function destroy()
{
    // Store all contents and delete the first one since this is created via seeder
    $contents = $this->contents->all()->toArray();
    array_shift($contents);

    // Delete db file, creates it from an example file and changes permissions
    system('rm -rf ../database/database.sqlite');
    system('cp ../database/database.sqlite.example ../database/database.sqlite');
    system('chmod 0777 ../database/');
    system('chmod 0777 ../database/database.sqlite');

    // Insert data
    foreach ($contents as $content) {
        $this->contents->create($content);
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Data has been destroyed!']);
}
```

However when I try to run it i get the error described in the title:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]General Error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database`

***I'm setting 777 permissions on the file and the folder*** as recommended by others questions' answers, so I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite: read-only database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319112/sqlite-read-only-database)

Comment: @MCMXCII I almost marked the question as the same dupe as well, but the question submitter does state "I'm giving 777 permissions to the file and the _folder_" in the last line of their question.

Comment: @cteski My bad, didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it by using to different methods, one to delete the DB and create again (returning all the contents) and then, the second one to insert all the contents to the new DB.

Answer (score 36):

You need to run two commands

First, change ownership of the Laravel directory to web group:

`sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/yourLarvelFolder`

Second, give privileges over storage directory so it can be writable:

`sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/yourLarvelFolder/storage`

Answer (score 4):

give permission here in ubuntu working on **18.04** and laravel **6**

```
sudo chmod -R 775 database
sudo chown -R $(whoami) database
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Fedora or Redhat with Selinux rememebr to switch off Selinux (or configure it correctly):

```
setenforce 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First run the following command to check apache2's user. Usually it is www-data

```
ps aux | grep "apache2"
```

Then run the following commands to resolve your issue.

```
chgrp -R www-data your_application_directory
chmod -R g+rw your_application_directory
```