# Drupal 9.2.6 - SQLite DB

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, server, drupal

I am new to Drupal 9 and new to SQLite.

I've developed a Drupal project locally and all is well. I am configuring a VPS to host this, and a few other Drupal projects. I've used an SQLite DB for ease.

The version on the server isn't working and it looks to be a DB issue. Any ideas?

**OS**
CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105

**> php --version**

PHP 7.4.25 (cli) (built: Oct 19 2021 15:18:10) ( NTS )

**> sqlite3 --version**

3.26.0 2018-12-01 12:34:55 bf8c1b2b7a5960c282e543b9c293686dccff272512d08865f4600fb58238alt1

**Browser message - 500 response**

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() (line 79 of /var/www/virtualhosts/protech/protech/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php).
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() (Line: 176)
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (Line: 212)
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters() (Line: 62)
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService() (Line: 176)
> Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (Line: 550)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition() (Line: 903)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 473)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 716)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)

**Apache logs**

> [20/Oct/2021:15:37:52 +0000] 500 0 2819 86.182.105.226 protech.targeted.agency "GET / HTTP/1.1" 1151 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36" - -

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48161083/2064829 maybe related.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. File/folder permission + selinux enforcement issue.