# Container File Permissions in Windows Container

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis, docker-for-windows

I've got a Windows Docker container (`microsoft/aspnet`) that is hosting a simple Web API. The web API accepts files from a form, saves them in a temp folder, does some processing, and then returns the result.

This works fine when deployed locally, but when done in my Docker container, I get a file permissions error on my temp folder (`App_Data`).

Is there a way to grant the IIS user the code is running as access to this file, or to open up the folder to any user for read/write access?

Current Docker file is below:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY ./Deploy/ /inetpub/wwwroot

RUN mkdir /inetpub/wwwroot/App_Data
```

Error message snippet I get running API from docker image:

```
"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Access to the path 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\App_Data\\BodyPart_481b6424-f9a5-4608-894d-406145a48445' is denied.","ExceptionType":"System.UnauthorizedAccessException"
```

It looks like there is a bug open on the aspnet-docker github about this same issue. [[link]](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-docker/issues/93)

In the meantime, it looks like running `cacls App_Data /G IIS_IUSRS:F` after starting the container fixes the issue temporarily.

Comment: Add `User Administrator` after `From` and remove -Credential from RUN statement

Comment: @GregorySuvalian Also, not sure where I should add `User Administrator`.. The `FROM` line only supports an image and a tag, and neither have a space, and I can't find an image/tag with that name

Comment: I meant put on new line `User Administrator`. See here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65e5e7d0-db0d-4dd4-b5f0-ab88aeb5cc27/build-image-from-nanoserver1709-get-an-access-denied-when-trying-to-set-system-variables-run-setx?forum=windowscontainers

Comment: Use PowerShell or `cacls` to grant IIS_IUSRS write permissions on `App_Data` folder in your `Dockerfile`. Also grant anonymous account the same permissions if you use anonymous authentication.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian adding the `USER Administrator` line as suggested gives the following error: `error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The user name or password is incorrect.`

Comment: Error which you specified is it coming from WebAPI running inside container or coming during build/run stage?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian Sorry, coming from the Docker build process

Comment: See if issue only appears if replace `microsoft/aspnet` with `microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016`

Comment: Also which version of Windows 10 are you running? Is it 1709 or below that?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian Same issue using `microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-ltsc2016` as suggested. Still seeing the same CreateProcess error when running `docker build`. Running latest version of Windows, v1709 and up-to-date Docker.

Comment: Can you post simpliest reproduction steps you can find which will show up the issue. It does not happen to me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unclear why, but `cacls` doesn't seem to be working when run as part of building the container. Switched to using `icacls`, and was able to grant the `IIS_USRS` permissions on the folder.

Line added to dockerfile:

`RUN icacls 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data' /grant 'IIS_IUSRS:(F)'`

Comment: This helped me solve an issue with a SQLite db in my Docker image (was running into [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319112/sqlite-read-only-database)). Just had to add a `/t` flag to the `icacls` command to grant access to all sub-folders.

Comment: @dillonius01 can you specify complete command by adding `/t` for better readbility in comment for people like who require subfolder access as well

Answer (score 5):

I can't comment as I don't have enough reputation, but if the answer by @Darendal doesn't work (which it did not for me), then try this syntax

```
RUN icacls C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data /grant "BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)F" /t
```

Comment: Thanks for that version. (OI) = directories object inherit. (CI) = directories container inherit. I needed that to set the permissions once and have future new files inherit the same permissions.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me running ASP.NET Web Site on .NET 4.8.  Not great but I needed write access in wwwroot because the app wrote files all over the place, so instead of App_Data I granted access to wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

My dockerfile did not accepted any of the other answers. Below is one more alernative.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8
SHELL ["powershell"] 
RUN & ICACLS "'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data'  /grant 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)F' /T"
```